# Is neck pain a common side-effect when diving?

Tags: football, injuries, goalkeeper, gaelic-football

I've been getting a lot of tightness in my shoulders and neck after doing diving practice. I wonder if it's because of the impact when I hit the ground and my head shakes a bit.

Are there any ways to lessen the impact?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the way you fall (technique). Players who try to naturally brace themselves when diving will feel pain in the shoulder and neck.If your technique is good you shouldn't feel pain in your neck and shoulders. Soreness in your hips are normal even with good technique though!